# What is the purpose of enc-u.tex in TeXLive?

Tags: texlive

There is this file

```
texmf-dist/tex/generic/enctex/enc-u.tex
```

Is it used anywhere?

There is a similar file

```
texmf-dist/tex/csplain/base/csenc-u.tex
```

which is used in csplain.ini, and is newer.

Comment: I searched the whole TeX Live tree, `enc-u.tex` seems to be unused.

Comment: My impression is that `enc-u.tex` is a template or some old file kept for back compatibility.